# Python: Usable Max and Min values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 2.x allows heterogeneous types to be compared.

A useful shortcut (in Python 2.7 here) is that `None` compares smaller than any integer or float value:

```
>>> None < float('-inf') < -sys.maxint * 2l < -sys.maxint
True
```

And in Python 2.7 an empty tuple `()` is an infinite value:

```
>>> () > float('inf') > sys.maxint
True
```

This shortcut is useful when one might sort a mixed list of ints and floats and want to have an absolute minimum and maximum to reference.

This shortcut has been removed in Python 3000 however (this is Python 3.2):

```
>>> None < 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
```

Furthermore, Python3000 [has removed](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers) `sys.maxint` on the theory that all ints promote to longs and the limit no longer applies.

[PEP 326](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0326/), A Case for Top and Bottom Values, advanced a reference min and max in Python. The new ordering behavior [documented](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons).

Since PEP 326 was rejected, what are useful, useable definitions for a min and max value that work with integers and floats and longs on Python 2X and Python 3000?

**Edit**

Several answers are along the lines of "just use maxv=float('inf')"... The reason I am thinking, however remote the possibility, is this:

```
>>> float(2**5000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

And:

```
>>> cmp(1.0**4999,10.0**5000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Yet:

```
>>> () > 2**5000
True
```

In order to cmp to a float value, `float('inf')`, the long value would need to be converted to a float and the conversion would cause an `OverflowError`...

**Conclusion**

Thank you everyone for your answers and comments. I picked TryPyPy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10577337/455276) because it seemed most inline with what I was asking: an absolute greatest and absolute least value as described in the Wikipedia [entry on infinity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity#Computing)

With this question, I learned that a long or int value is not converted to a float in order to complete the comparison of `float('inf') > 2**5000`. I did not know that.

Comment: What's wrong with `float("inf")` or, if you need a number, `sys.float_info.max`?

Comment: IIRC hetrogeneous values where ordered alphabetically by the name of their type - hardly ever useful

Comment: "Python3000 has removed sys.maxint on the theory that all ints promote to longs and the limit no longer applies.", No, Python3000 has removed `int` *period*. All integers are now `long`, which is why it was renamed.

Comment: @gnibbler I imagine it was a little more complicated than that. Which makes sorting a list of `(typename, value)`, the trivial solution, not the same as the old way (but it shouldn't be too hard, even if hacky as hell).

Comment: @carrot-top  `print(2**5000000 > float('inf'))` prints `False` as expected...

Comment: @TryPyPy, Actually it's even simpler :) see http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__

Comment: Aha, I found a place `float("inf")` doesn't work but my cheating MAX/MIN do: `print(list(sorted([float("nan"), float("inf"), float("-inf"), float("nan"), float("nan")])))`.

Comment: "In order to cmp to a float value, float('inf'), the long value would need to be converted to a float."  No, that's not the way that float to long (or float to int) comparison works.  (It can't work that way, since then you'd lose transitivity of equality, with all sorts of dire consequences for dict and set containment.) Comparing `float('inf')` with 10**1000 should not raise OverflowError.

Comment: @carrot-top Your current points against float('inf') aren't good, as Pyson says. Now, Mark Dickinson is the current maintainer of everything numerical in CPython core and lib. If he also says float('inf') is OK, I wouldn't bother looking for more counterexamples.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I think there are good answers here already;  I'm kinda reluctant to post another one that doesn't add anything new.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: Thank you for your comments anyway -- and your invaluable help on Python.

Comment: () is greater than all numbers by virtue of the fact that Python 2.7 orders by type name for different types (and 'tuple' is greater than the numeric type names). But if your list contains tuples note that () is actually less than all other tuples. The value xrange(0) is greater than all tuples.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For numerical comparisons, `+- float("inf")` should work.

It doesn't always work (but covers the realistic cases):

```
print(list(sorted([float("nan"), float("inf"), float("-inf"), float("nan"), float("nan")])))
# NaNs sort above and below +-Inf
# However, sorting a container with NaNs makes little sense, so not a real issue.
```

To have objects that compare as higher or lower to any other arbitrary objects (including `inf`, but excluding other cheaters like below), you can create classes that state their max/min-ness in their special methods for comparisons:

```
class _max:
    def __lt__(self, other): return False
    def __gt__(self, other): return True

class _min:
    def __lt__(self, other): return True
    def __gt__(self, other): return False

MAX, MIN = _max(), _min()

print(list(sorted([float("nan"), MAX, float('inf'), MIN, float('-inf'), 0,float("nan")])))
# [<__main__._min object at 0xb756298c>, nan, -inf, 0, inf, nan, <__main__._max object at 0xb756296c>]
```

Of course, it takes more effort to cover the 'or equal' variants. And it will not solve the general problem of being unable to sort a  list containing `None`s and `int`s, but that too should be possible with a little wrapping and/or decorate-sort-undecorate magic (e.g. sorting a list of tuples of `(typename, value)`).

Comment: FWIW, this kind of cheating breaks when you suddenly have many MINs (or equivalent cheaters) in a container, even worse if it's a auto-sorting one.

Answer (score 11):

You have the most obvious choices in your question already: `float('-inf')` and `float('inf')`.

Also, note that `None` being less than everything and the empty tuple being higher than everything wasn't ever *guaranteed* in Py2, and, eg, Jython and PyPy are perfectly entitled to use a different ordering if they feel like it. All that is guaranteed is consistency within one running copy of the interpreter - the actual order is arbitrary.

Comment: You can even assign the float forms of infinity to `MAX` and `MIN` and be on your way.

Comment: `3>> float('-inf') < (3+4j)`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
`TypeError: unorderable types: float() < complex()`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: not really fair, as any list containing complex numbers only is also unsortable (and any pair of complexes, for that matter) :)

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, `float('nan')` can sort higher than `float('inf')` (because both > and < return false between the two), but I think a custom MAX/MIN solves that.

Comment: @TryPyPy only for limited definitions of 'solved'. That brokenness is caused by having NaNs in a container to be sorted to start with, rather than by `float(inf)` not being a 'true' max for numeric types. This is exemplified by NaNs being able to appear all over the place in a 'sorted' container, and not even floating together. All that a custom MAX/MIN guarantees is they won't be first or last; how useful that is depends on the use case, of course, but it seems that just filtering out NaNs would usually be better.

Comment: @lvc Agreed, so for realistic purposes float('inf') is still the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

In cPython, the cmp does not perform a conversion to float implicitly. i.e., this works:

```
>>> float('inf') > 2**5000
True
```

While this explicitly performs the dread conversion:

```
>>> float('inf') > float(2**5000)
Overflow...
```

The *correct* answer, IMHO, is not a value per se by a change in logic:

```
def func_with_min():
   minval=None
   for loop in list_with_mins:
      if minval is None or minval<minseen:
          # do that min thing you wanna do...
```

If you want to have *a value* then `float('-inf')` for min and `float('inf')` is pretty safe. Be sure to cache that outside of a loop however:

```
def func():
   minval=float('-inf')
   for loop in now_you_can_loop:
       # otherwise float('-inf') is kinda slow
```

Comment: `>>> cmp(1.0**4999,10.0**5000)`

Comment: and `cmp()` is gone in Py3 too.

Comment: It's the `**` operations that are giving you the `OverflowError`s here.    Nothing to do with the comparison.

Comment: Which is faster?  Comparing to inf or checking if x is None on every loop?